# Atomic design typescript react

Tags: reactjs, typescript, atomic-design

```
import React from "react"
import styled, { css } from "styled-components"

import * as Router from "react-router-dom"

const styles = css`
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #0b0080;
  &:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
  }
`

const StyledLink = styled(({ ...props }) => <Router.Link {...props} />)`
  ${styles};
`
const Anchor = styled.a`
  ${styles};
`
type LinkProps = {
  to: string | null
  href: string | null
  target?: string
}

export const Link: React.FunctionComponent<LinkProps> = ({ ...props }) => {
  const { to } = props
  if (to) {
    return <StyledLink {...props} />
  }

  return <Anchor {...props} />
}

Link.defaultProps = {
  to: null,
  href: null,
}
```

I am trying to use atomic design for my project & I am starting with my Link component It checks if there is a to prop to it renders a default the `StyledLink` component but It seems I am getting this error from the `Anchor` component

`Overload 2 of 2, '(props: StyledComponentPropsWithAs<"a", any, {}, never>): ReactElement<StyledComponentPropsWithAs<"a", any, {}, never>, string | ... 1 more ... | (new (props: any) => Component<...>)>', gave the following error. Type '{ to: string | null; href: string | null; target?: string | undefined; children?: ReactNode; }' is not assignable to type 'Pick<Pick<Pick<DetailedHTMLProps<AnchorHTMLAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement>, HTMLAnchorElement>, "style" | ... 257 more ... | "rel"> & { ...; }, "ref" | ... 258 more ... | "rel"> & Partial<...>, "ref" | ... 258 more ... | "rel">'. Types of property 'href' are incompatible. Type 'string | null' is not assignable to type 'string | undefined'. Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string | undefined'.  TS2769`

Any ides whats's wrong?

Comment: Looks like you are passing in a null-able string, into an optional string property (`href`). null !== undefined in JS

Comment: `Link.defaultProps = { to: undefined, href: undefined}` and also in `LinkProps` replace `null`

Comment: Why and how its related to atomic design?

Comment: `TypeScript error: Property 'href' is missing in type '{ children: Element; to: string; target: string; }' but required in type 'LinkProps'. `  Getting this now even to though `href` already has default prop